# jquery - defining different options per element

Tags: jquery, button

I'm writing a quick plugin (one of my first) to help with buttons if js enabled:

```
(function ($) {
$.fn.extend({
    chemButton : function (options) {
        return this.each(function () {
            myoptions = $.extend({ x: '0px', y: '0px', xHover: '0px', yHover: '0px', xActive: '0px', yActive: '0px' }, options);
            var ob = $(this);
            ob.addClass('chemButton');
            var focus = false;
            ob.mousedown(function() {
                focus = true;
                ob.children()
                    .css({ 'background-position' : myoptions.xActive + " " + myoptions.yActive })
                    .addClass('VBfocus')
                    .removeClass('VBHover');
            });
            ob.mouseup(function(){
                focus = false;
                ob.children()
                    .css({ 'background-position' : myoptions.xHover + " " + myoptions.yHover })
                    .removeClass('VBfocus')
                    .addClass('VBHover');
                window.location.href = ob.find('a').attr('href');
            });
            if (focus === false) {
                ob.children().hover(function () {
                    ob.children()
                        .css({ 'background-position' : myoptions.xHover + " " + myoptions.yHover })
                        .removeClass('VBfocus')
                        .addClass('VBHover')
                        .find('a').addClass('VBHover');
                }, function () {
                    if (focus === false) {
                        ob.children()
                            .css({ 'background-position' : myoptions.x + " " + myoptions.y })
                            .removeClass('VBfocus')
                            .removeClass('VBHover')
                            .find('a').removeClass('VBHover');
                    }
                });
            }
        });
    }
});
})(jQuery);
```

When having 2 separate buttons using my plugin i.e

```
<script type="text/javascript">
$(document).ready(function(){
    $('.panelButton').chemButton({ x: '0px', y: '0px', xHover: '0', yHover: '-30px', xActive: '0', yActive: '-60px' });
    $('.panelButton2').chemButton({ x: '0px', y: '-30px', xHover: '0', yHover: '-60px', xActive: '0', yActive: '0px' });
});
</script>
```

the last declared options is applied to both buttons. How do I apply it only to the element it is intended for?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Not sure if this is the cause or not, but shouldn't

```
myoptions = $.extend({ x: '0px', y: '0px', xHover: '0px', yHover: '0px', xActive: '0px', yActive: '0px' }, options);
```

be

```
var myoptions = $.extend({ x: '0px', y: '0px', xHover: '0px', yHover: '0px', xActive: '0px', yActive: '0px' }, options);
```

I suspect that by not declaring myoptions as a var, it's promoting it all the way up to the global/window level, and being overridden each time.

Answer (score 0):

You should declare your options **before** this line:

```
return this.each(function () {
```

Try this line:

```
var myoptions = $.extend({}, { x: '0px', y: '0px', xHover: '0px', yHover: '0px', xActive: '0px', yActive: '0px' }, options);
```

and delete your previous line "myoptions" inside each() function.